# where exactly is the rails "root" function defined?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scope, rails-routing

I see something like the following in a rails applications:

```
Application.routes.draw do
    root :to => "accounts#index"
end
```

I'm told [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#using-root) that this will define where rails routes to if "/" is the path asked for. However, where the heck is this 'root' function defined in rails code? I don't understand what scoping issues are involved to get this trick to work.

I can see that a block is being passed to the `draw` function. So I'm assuming that the `draw` function calls `yield` to execute the passed block. But I'm still not sure why the `root` function will magically be inside the scope of the passed block.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`root` is defined on `ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper::Base`, which is included by `ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper`.

There is a little more going on behind the scenes than at first glance.

If we look at the definition of `draw`, we can see why:

```
# action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb
def draw(&block)
  # ...
  eval_block(block)
  # ...
end
```

The block is converted to a proc (with `&`) and passed to `eval_block` which is defined a bit farther down:

```
def eval_block(block)
  # ...
  mapper = Mapper.new(self)
  # ...
  mapper.instance_exec(&block)
end
```

So, as it turns out, `yield` isn't used at all. The block we pass to `Application.routes.draw` is just being evaluated in the context of an instance of `ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper`.

If we add `puts self` to our `config/routes.rb`, we can see this in action:

```
Application.routes.draw do
  puts self
end
```

When we run `rake routes` we get something similar to the following:

```
#<ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper:0x007feadf52cbd8>
# ...
```

For further reading, see:

http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Object.html#method-i-instance_exec
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb#LC296
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb#LC336
[http://www.amazon.com/Metaprogramming-Ruby-Program-Like-Pros/dp/1934356476](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1934356476)

Comment: Fabulous post!! Thank you for your effort.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb

```
def root(options = {})
  options = { :to => options } if options.is_a?(String)
  match '/', { :as => :root, :via => :get }.merge!(options)
end
```

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing.rb

```
module Routing
  autoload :Mapper, 'action_dispatch/routing/mapper'
```